# Delete the first known character in a string with sed

Tags: sed

How does one delete the first known character in a string with sed?

For example, say I want to delete the first character (which is @) in the string "@ABCDEFG1234"

I want sed to verify whether "@" exists as the first character. If so, it should delete the character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`sed 's/^@\(.*\)/\1/'`

`^` means beginning of the string

`@` your known char

`(.*)` the rest, captured

then captured block will be substituted to output
Sorry, can't test it at the moment, but should be something like that

Comment: I want to delete `+` which does not need to be escaped although it stands for 1 or more in regex.

Answer (score 31):

There's no need to capture and replace.

```
sed 's/^@//'
```

This replaces the character `@` when it's first `^` in the string, with nothing. Thus, deleting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this instead.

> sed 's/^.//'

```
^ - Starting character 
. - No of charactes(.. means two characters)
```

Example :

```
echo test123 | sed 's/^.//'
est123
echo test123 | sed 's/^..//'
st123
```

Comment: The question says “I want sed to verify whether "@" exists as the first character. If so, it should delete the character.” Your answer deletes the first character of each line no matter what is it. For example, if a line contains `test123`, it looks like the OP wants it left alone.

Comment: I like the quick solution of Prakaash, but @Scott you are right when reading the OP carefully. In most of the cases, you do want a distinct character and not any.